# pandas: dataframe from dict with comma separated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a DataFrame from a nested dictionary, where the values are in comma separated strings.

Each value is nested in a dict, such as:

```
dict = {"1":{
             "event":"A, B, C"},
        "2":{
             "event":"D, B, A, C"},
        "3":{
             "event":"D, B, C"}
        }
```

My desired output is:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   A   B   C   NaN
1   A   B   C   D
2   NaN B   C   D
```

All I have so far is converting the dict to dataframe and splitting the items in each list. But I'm not sure this is getting me any closer to my objective.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
Out[439]: 
           1           2        3
event  A, B, C  D, B, A, C  D, B, C

In [441]: df.loc['event'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[441]: 
   0   1   2    3
1  A   B   C  NaN
2  D   B   A    C
3  D   B   C  NaN
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do not use key words as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have(modified the split a little to strip the extra spaces) `df1`, you can probably just `stack` the result and use `pd.crosstab()` on the index and value column:

```
df1 = df.loc['event'].str.split('\s*,\s*').apply(pd.Series) 

df2 = df1.stack().rename('value').reset_index()
pd.crosstab(df2.level_0, df2.value)

#   value   A   B   C   D
# level_0               
#       1   1   1   1   0
#       2   1   1   1   1
#       3   0   1   1   1
```

This is not exactly as you asked for, but I imagine you may prefer this to your desired output.

To get exactly what you are looking for, you can add an extra column which is equal to the value column above and then unstack the index that contains the values:

```
df2 = df1.stack().rename('value').reset_index()
df2['value2'] = df2.value
df2.set_index(['level_0', 'value']).drop('level_1', axis = 1).unstack(level = 1)

#         value2
#   value   A     B     C     D
# level_0               
#       1   A     B     C  None
#       2   A     B     C     D
#       3   None  B     C     D
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom, this is exactly what I wanted. And actually the first numeric version works even better for my case :) . Rgds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of comprehensions to massage the nested dict into a better format for creation of a DataFrame that flags if an entry for the column exists or not:

```
the_dict = {"1":{
             "event":"A, B, C"},
        "2":{
             "event":"D, B, A, C"},
        "3":{
             "event":"D, B, C"}
        }

df = pd.DataFrame([[{z:1 for z in y.split(', ')} for y in x.values()][0] for x in the_dict.values()])
>>> df

     A  B  C    D
0  1.0  1  1  NaN
1  1.0  1  1  1.0
2  NaN  1  1  1.0
```

Once you've made the DataFrame you can simply loop through the columns and convert the values that flagged the existence of the letter into a letter using the `where` method(below this does where NaN leave as NaN, otherwise it inserts the letter for the column):

```
for col in df.columns:
    df_mask = df[col].isnull()
    df[col]=df[col].where(df_mask,col)
>>> df

     A  B  C    D
0    A  B  C  NaN
1    A  B  C    D
2  NaN  B  C    D
```

Based on @merlin's suggestion you can go straight to the answer within the comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[{z:z for z in y.split(', ')} for y in x.values()][0] for x in the_dict.values()])
>>> df
     A  B  C    D
0    A  B  C  NaN
1    A  B  C    D
2  NaN  B  C    D
```

Comment: or try z:1 >>> z:z